# Decompiling a pyz file to and decompiling all pyc files not resulting in source code

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, decompiling

I am extracting an executable I created for security and testing purposes.

I have decompiled the pyz files.  It seems the original file called "HAX" does not appear as a pyc file.  I am using [pyinstractor](http://eurcodewiki.blogspot.com.es/2010/08/python-how-to-decompile-files-from.html).   I can decompile all the libraries but there is no benefit to that.

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere? :)

Comment: @MikeStrobel Haha, yes.  I have a lot of pyc files but wheres the pyc source file.  I don't care about all these imports :).

Comment: @TysonDogerzonda I'm still missing a question.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake I decompiled all the pyc files so I guess I answered my own question.  I'm trying to decompile source code but I could not find it despite decompiling every single pyc file visible.

Comment: So is the real question why decompiling did not result in the expected source?

Comment: Yes, what you said.  Haha

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.